# How to Cast Fragment's context to interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-asynctask

I want to use return a value from `AsyncTask` class by using **interface**. Problem is that my following code is work fine in Activity but not in fragment class.

I got `ClassCastException` like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.demo.HomeActivity cannot be cast to com.demo.helper.OnTaskCompleteListener
at com.demo.util.JSONParseAsync.<init>(JSONParseAsync.java:33)
at com.demo.fragment.PersonalDetailFragment.loadProfileAction(PersonalDetailFragment.java:93)
at com.demo.fragment.PersonalDetailFragment.onCreate(PersonalDetailFragment.java:81)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1942)
```

Interface class:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleteListener {

void onTaskComplete(JSONObject jsonObject);

}
```

PersonalDetailFragment class:

```
public class PersonalDetailFragment extends Fragment  implements OnTaskCompleteListener {
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_detail, container,
            false);
    loadProfileAction();
    return view;
}
private void loadProfileAction() {

    SessionPreference preference = new SessionPreference(getActivity());
    try {
        String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(preference.getSessionId(), "UTF-8")
                + ","
                + URLEncoder.encode(Constants.URL_TOKEN, "UTF-8");
        // URL base64Encode
        String processUrl = Base64.encodeToString(encodedUrl.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);

        JSONParseAsync parseAsync = new JSONParseAsync(getContext()); // also try getActivity()
        parseAsync.execute((URLConstants.GET_USER_DETAIL_URL+processUrl).trim());

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {

        boolean status = jsonObject.getBoolean(URLConstants.TAG_STATUS);

        Log.e(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "Status:- " + status);

        if (status == true) {
            JSONArray dataarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(URLConstants.TAG_DATA);
            JSONObject data = dataarray.getJSONObject(0);
            fillProfileData(data);

        } else if (status == false) {
            Snackbar.make(view,
                    "Incorrect User Name OR Password",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Log.i("GARG", "Excution Line Finish ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JSONParseAsync class:

```
public class JSONParseAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

private Context mContext;

ProgressDialog mProgress;
private OnTaskCompleteListener mCallback;

public JSONParseAsync(Context context){
    this.mContext = (AppCompatActivity)context;
    this.mCallback = (OnTaskCompleteListener) mContext;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... URL) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    try{
    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "line excucation 2 doInBackground");
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    String url = URL[0];
    Log.d(Constants.ACTIVITY_TAG, "...." + url);
    // Making a request to url and getting response.

    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d(Constants.JSON_TAG, "" + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {

            jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            Log.e(Constants.JSON_TAG, "" + jsonObj);

    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObj;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "line excucation 1 onPreexcute");
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mProgress.setMessage("Downloading nPlease wait...");
    mProgress.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "line excucation 3 onProgressUpdate");
    mProgress.setMessage(values[0]);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "line excucation 3 onPostExecute");
    mProgress.dismiss();
    //This is where you return data back to caller
    Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, " final result:- "+result);
    mCallback.onTaskComplete(result);
}

}
```

Please help me:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing this

```
JSONParseAsync parseAsync = new JSONParseAsync(getContext());
```

you're sending the `Activity` to your `AsyncTask`, but it is your `Fragment` that implements `OnTaskCompleteListener`.

Either have your `Activity` implement your interface, **or**

do this :

```
JSONParseAsync parseAsync = new JSONParseAsync(this, getContext());
```

and change your `AsyncTask` constructor to

```
public JSONParseAsync(OnTaskCompleteListener listener, Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    //this.mContext = (AppCompatActivity)context; -> you don't need that cast, AppCompatActivity is a subclass of Context
    this.mCallback = listener;
}
```

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you ;) Happy coding !

Comment: @2Dee Rocks .Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 Parameters for your Tasks Constructor:

```
public JSONParseAsync(Context context, OnTaskCompleteListener listener){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCallback = listener;
}
```

and create a new instance by using

```
    JSONParseAsync parseAsync = new JSONParseAsync(getContext(), this);
```

Because when you pass the Context, you don't pass the fragment but the underlying activity. So you'll probaly need 2 parameters if you want to use your task inside your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is, because you have passed the Activity context to `JSONParseAsync` and inside its constructor you are casting it to activity `AppCompatActivity` following the activity casting to your `OnTaskCompleteListener`.. So, your activity should be implementing the listener and not your fragment.

just let `HomeActivity` implement your interface `OnTaskCompleteListener`.

**Example:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTaskCompleteListener{
...
}
```

In my opinion, don't create your custom classes unless and until its required. In your case you should have achieved your task with anonymous class too.. there's no need to create separate class..

I hope you got my point.

Still, what you can do is, pass the context and OnTaskCompleteListener in the constructor

```
private void loadProfileAction() {
...

        JSONParseAsync parseAsync = new JSONParseAsync(getContext(), this); // also try getActivity()
        ...

}
```

and change the constructor to:

```
public JSONParseAsync(Context context, OnTaskCompleteListener listener){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCallback = listener;
}
```

Comment: @Garg's Then, why have you created the interface ?

Comment: b'coz i need to call JSONParseAsync class multi time in project so need a return json result.

Comment: yeah sure sir.. i check it &+1 for it. thank for help me.